# Why are the basic rules of World of Darkness stated after chapters that require understanding the rules?

Tags: world-of-darkness, publishing

In World of Darkness the very basic rules like rolling dice are stated pages and pages after not so basic rules are. For example, the Disciplines are all described by their effects narrated, then with the system to use it. If you come from computer games, "three health levels" might seem like very minor damage, while it actually isn't, etc. Unless you understand the basic rules, things like "three blood points" or "one health level" won't make any sense -- hence neither the Disciplines descriptions would. Hey, you don't even know how to make rolls yet!

**So why are the very basic rules like rolling dice, resolving combat and applying damage stated after the rules to use Disciplines, not before them?**

Comment: Questions that are [basically rants are off topic](//rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3):

RPG text has several cross purposes, most notably instruction and reference. The game designers chose to emphasize what makes the game unique early, both for reference and perhaps to initially entice a first reader to continue, over explaining the core mechanics.